# How to change the default Browser in Expression Blend

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I want to set IE as my default browser for running Silver light applications from Expression Blend, but I don't want to change my windows default from Mozilla. Is there a settings option in Blend to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now there is not a setting to do that.  It will use the default configured browser.